# What is the current science on entropic gravity?

Tags: gravity, entropy

In the past couple of years there has been some buzz about ['entropic gravity'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_gravity), including here on [stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4289) in Jan 2011.  Many say that there is no way that gravity can be entropic, while others think it is an interesting idea and bears more research.

Has a consensus been reached on entropic gravity?  Is the discussion exactly the same as it was a year ago when the previous question was asked?

Comment: Linked [Phys.SE post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4289/2451) is possible duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most recent retort to entropic gravity I've seen is [this arXiv article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4161).

Abstract:
"We argue that neutron interference experiments and experiments on gravitational bound states of neutron unambiguously disprove entropic origin of gravitation. The criticism expressed in a recent paper [7] concerning our arguments against entropic gravity is shown to be invalid."

Kobakhidze considers the influence of entropic gravity on quantum mechanical systems and concludes that it deviates significantly from standard predictions and observation. This appears to be due to the small number of statistical microstates that the systems can take on changing the entropic gravitation Hamiltonian from the standard Hamiltonian.

This isn't really a consensus, but it's the most recent and most forceful argument I've seen on this topic.

Comment: I am not an expert, but the first two papers listed on [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/cits/1108.4161) as citations on the paper you list seem to leave the door open for entropic gravity once it is further developed.   Anyway, the verdict still seems to be out.  Thanks for your answer.