# What is the physical basis for entropic gravity?

Tags: gravity, entropy

There is much ado about emergent gravity these days. But what's the physical basis for this entropic force? In a stretching piece of rubber the molecules of rubber provide the basis, but what is the physical basis for entropic gravity?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4289/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article in Scientific American this month about emergent space/time from quantum entanglement "Tangled up in Spacetime"January 2017. It looks at the hologram equivalence of 3Dimention with Time and Gravity  and one of a 2Dimention  on a higher plane without them. There seems to be a relationship to entanglement and spacetime.  There is also work recently done that mapped energy density (basis of gravity) and  entanglement from a  2D plane to a 3D plane, where gravity was not considered fundamental but emergent. It was based on there being particles of  spacetime, without caring what these particles are.